# Double ForLooping (over DataFrame & List)

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, nan

I have this test2 dataframe:

```
   manufacturer  condition   fuel        drive  cylinders       description
0   ford        excellent    gas          rwd    NaN            ford in excellent condition. 4 cylinders
1   cadillac    NaN          NaN          NaN    4 cylinders    4 cylinders. Half-new cadillac. Diesel.
2   NaN         new          diesel       fwd    12 cylinders   Ford, diesel, new condition.
3   NaN         NaN          electric     NaN    10 cylinders   Ferrari, excellent condition. 4wd
4   ferrari     NaN          NaN          4wd    NaN            New ferrari. Electric with 12 cylinders.
```

And I want to loop over the dataframe and fill the NaN values of each column using the information of the column "description". To that end I have done this:

```
import re

manufacturer = '(ford | cadillac | ferrari)'
condition = '(excellent, good, fair, like new, salvage, new)'
fuel = '(gas, hybrid, diesel, electric)'
drive = '(\S*wd)'
cylinders = '(\d+\s+cylinders?)'

test2['manufacturer'] = test2['manufacturer'].fillna(
    test2['description'].str.extract(manufacturer, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)).str.lower()
test2['condition'] = test2['condition'].fillna(
    test2['description'].str.extract(condition, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)).str.lower()
test2['fuel'] = test2['fuel'].fillna(
    test2['description'].str.extract(fuel, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)).str.lower()
test2['drive'] = test2['drive'].fillna(
    test2['description'].str.extract(drive, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)).str.lower()
test2['cylinders'] = test2['cylinders'].fillna(
    test2['description'].str.extract(cylinders, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)).str.lower()

test2
```

But it doesn't look that good so I tried to do a for loop to simplify the programming:

```
columns = [manufacturer, condition, fuel, drive, cylinders]

for i in test2:
   for column in columns:
      test2[i] = test2[i].fillna(
        test2['description'].str.extract(column, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)).str.lower()
```

And it keeps giving me errors no matter how I try. It loops fine over the "i" in the test2 but the loop gets an error when it starts looping over the list "columns"...

Any idea how could I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: The list should be called `columns`, not `column`

Comment: ah sorry, it is called columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping multiple times per element. You you should only loop once per element. Use the `zip` function` to merge the keys and list.

Try this code:

```
keys =    ['manufacturer', 'condition', 'fuel', 'drive', 'cylinders']
columns = [ manufacturer,   condition,   fuel,   drive,   cylinders]

for i,column in zip(keys,columns):
   test2[i] = test2[i].fillna(
      test2['description'].str.extract(column, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)).str.lower()
```